# How to handle showing multiple categories at one table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working on an Online Store project using Laravel 8 and in this project there are 4 types of categories:

```
Main Category (such as supermaket)
Superior Category (such as dairy & ...)
Secondary Category (such as cheese & ...)
Secondary Sub Category (such as cream cheese & ...)
```

And for each Category I have made a separated Model and table.

And all tables goes with same fields:

[image]

So this is the capture of `superior_categories` with parent id of **1** which is the id of `supermarket` main category.

And this is the One To Many relationship for the `MainCategory` Model:

```
class MainCategory extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['name','short_name','description','pciture'];
    protected $table = 'main_categories';

    public function superiors()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SuperiorCategory::class);
    }
}
```

Now I need to show ALL the categories at one table, so my question is should I retrieve all the categories separately like this:

```
public function index()
    {
        $mainCategory = MainCategory::all();
        $superiorCategory = SuperiorCategory::all();
        $cat = Cat::all();
        $subcat = Subcat::all();

        return view('admin.categories.index', compact('mainCategory','superiorCategory','cat','subcat'));
    }
```

Or there is another better way for doing this.

In fact, how to handle showing multiple categories at one table properly

Comment: In my opinion, you should only have 1 `Catrgories` table. You can add a column to identify different types, and each can have a `parent_id`. This would be a Recursive relationship, where each Category can have multiple children, each with their own children. You're gonna make this really hard for yourself by splitting this to multiple Tables/Models. Also, `Cat` is not a great model name; I don't think `Category` when I read that, I think 

Comment: What's the difference between your MainCategory and SuperiorCategory model?

Answer (score 0):

There's no clean way to do this, here is however a dirty way:

```
class MainCategory extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['name','short_name','description','pciture'];
    protected $table = 'main_categories';
    protected $with = [ 'parent' ];

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SuperiorCategory::class);
    }

    public function getAncestorsAttribute() {
        return collect($this->parent)->concat($this->parent?->ancestors??[]);
    }
}
```

Then if you do `$model->ancestors` you should get them. However this will have to do one query per ancestor every time you load one of the `MainCategory` models which may end up being very expensive.

This assumes that your SuperiorCategory model has a similar arrangement

Answer (score -1):

This is not a good structure for multi-level categories in your DB. Instead, it would be best to have a table for categories and store parent categories or another level in a column like `category_id`.

**Example**

[image]